# Having problems mapping down the json data

Tags: swift

I am having problems with mapping down some json data that are coming from the API, A lot of errors are coming and I am really having a difficult time dealing with this one since I am new to swift.

Structure:

```
{
  "StatusCode": 0,
  "Result": [
   {
     "Type": "Test",
     "Date": "Test",
     "Message": "Test"
   },
   {
     "Type": "Test",
     "Date": "Test",
     "Message": "Test"
   }
 ]
}
```

My Structure That is not Working:

```
struct Notifications: Decodable {
    struct NotificationsStructure: Decodable {
    
    var Type: String?
    var Date: String?
    var Message: String?
   }

   var StatusCode: Int
   var Result: NotificationsStructure!
}
```

Comment: as you can see from your data `Result` is an array, so try using this: `var Result: [NotificationsStructure]`, and if it can ever be null add "?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all **never** declare a property in a `Decodable` object as implicit unwrapped optional. If it can be missing or be `nil` declare it as regular optional (`?`) otherwise non-optional.

In JSON there are only two collection types:

- **dictionary** represented by `{}`,
- **array** represented by `[]`

The value for key `Result` is clearly an array.

And add `CodingKeys` to map the capitalized keys to lowercase property names

```
struct Notifications: Decodable {
    struct NotificationsStructure: Decodable {

        private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case type = "Type", date = "Date", message = "Message"
        }
    
        let type: String
        let date: String
        let message: String
   }

   private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case statusCode = "StatusCode", result = "Result",
   }

   let statusCode: Int
   let result: [NotificationsStructure]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, Can you please explain how can I assign the Message to example a tableView IBOutlet in form of string like this for example:  Result.Notification.Message or otherwise?

Answer (score -1):

The response from result is an **array type** . You should create another object that have same properties of each array.

```
struct NotificationResponse : Decodable {
   let StatusCode : Int
   let Result: [Notification]
}

struct Notification : Decodable {
   let Type: String
   let Date: String
   let Message: String
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer so if I try to access the Message from the result array how do i achieve that? , By doing Result.Notification.Message or otherwise?